# AlertDialog.Builder create does not return

Tags: android

Because of my frustration that there was no clear error message (no exception or whatever), I want to prevent people having the same problem.

Here's the problem:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity);
...
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); // <-- does not return!
dialog.show();  // <-- never gets hit
```

Comment: What you are passing inside AlertDialog.Builder()??? Pass activity name or getApplicationContext()

Comment: no contents in alert dialog??

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I just added this question to help other people who run into this, as I did not find a StackOverflow question yet on this. I answered it myself already. I added 'MyActivity' to be clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it never returns, is because it is not being run from the UI thread.

Check if you are running this on the UI thread adding this:

```
boolean uithread = Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper();
```